# Badly received (bad) first question - should I edit it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A new user has asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399217/vba-code-to-compare-two-identical-excel-report-and-generate-difference-report) which as garnered 5 downvotes because it's well, not a good question...

With the information the user has added in the comments, this could be improved...but still probably wouldn't be perfect

But should we be doing this to help out a new user, or just let the question be closed because the new user hasn't taken the time to ask properly and read the guidance?

Comment: You can do both. Edit the question into shape with the info you got and then close vote as unclear / too broad if it still isn't answerable. But don't polish turds ...

Comment: With the spotlight of meta, chances are it'll get closed and sent to oblivion rather quickly.

Comment: I think you're right - even with the comments it wouldn't make a half-decent question, as we can't really guess what the OP is asking!

Comment: Side note: does this question really deserve 12 comments? Why doesn't everyone [save some time and] upvote the first, vote-to-close and move on?

Comment: Very hard to see how you could possibly rescue this question with an edit.  You can't just make up stuff that explains why the OP can't complete this task by himself.  As-is, reactivating this question is unnecessary and harmful, taking attention away from questions that deserve our attention.

Answer (score 5):

> With the information the user has added in the comments, this could be
>   improved...but still probably wouldn't be perfect

Never let perfect be the enemy of good!

You have edit privileges to ... edit. If you can find enough ammunition in the comments to bring the question out of the closable range and make it on topic, by all means go for it.

Remember, the primary purpose here isn't to appropriately punish people who don't do research, but to make good questions and good answers such that they help future visitors.

Comment: perfection is baloney, good is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

> With the information the user has added in the comments, this could be improved...but still probably wouldn't be perfect

Okay, it wouldn't be perfect, but would it be *good*?  Would the edited question be a slightly less terrible question that's still terrible, or a question that's good but not great?

If the latter is the case, make the edit, if the former is the case, don't.

Editing questions that are still going to be bad questions meriting closure *after your edit* is not productive.  It's spending a bunch of time that's likely to be wasted, as the question still won't be answerable, and your edit will just draw more attention to a bad question, attracting more downvotes, close votes, and wasting the time of those people that could be better spent on a question that's actually worth their time.

If you can either salvage a question, turning it into a good one, or make an already okay question *even better*, then that's both a better use of your time, and far more helpful to others.

Comment: I think I agree with Hans' comment - we can't really guess enough from the OP comments to turn it into a proper question, so this one's a loser...